# Determining if a function is unitary.

Tags: functional-analysis

Fix $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ with $\lambda \ne 0$ and define a mapping on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ by:

$(Uf)(t) = |\lambda|^{1/2}f(\lambda t)$.

Show that U is unitary.

Proof so far:
To show U is unitary you need to show it is linear, surjective and an isometry. To proof it is linear is straight forward so i'll omit the details. To proof it is surjective should be obvious. But I'm stuck on proving it is an isometry.

Defining the norm as : $|| f ||^2 = \int |f(t)|^2 dt$. For isometry, we require, $||Uf|| = ||f||$.

We have,

$||Uf||^2 = \int |(Uf)(t)|^2 dt = |\lambda|\int |f(\lambda t)|^2 dt$.

The question seems to imply that $U$ is an isometry as long as $\lambda \ne 0$. However the above suggests that it is only an isometry if $\lambda = 1$.

Can anyone suggest a hint as to how to show that $U$ is in fact an isometry?

Answer (score 0):

Proving $U$ is an isometry amounts to proving
$$
|\lambda|\int |f(\lambda t)|^2\,dt = \int |f(t)|^2\,dt
$$
which looks like a standard application of a $u$-substitution from high school calculus. Namely, if you can show
$$
\int g(cx)\,dx = \frac1{|c|}\int g(x)\,dx
$$
you will be done. This last fact can be proved by showing it holds for simple functions, then using monotone convergence to extend this to positive functions, etc.